Resolving Path Issues for Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools on 64-bit System: Not Detected by CMake"
I'm experiencing a problem where CMake cannot locate the Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools on my 64-bit Windows machine. Here's a detailed description of my issue:
Visual Studio Build Tools Installation: I noticed that the Visual Studio Build Tools were not present on my system as there was no folder named "BuildTools" under any directory. To address this, I ran the installer directly from the official link ([vs_BuildTools.exe][1]). After installation, the Visual Studio installer shows it as "Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 (2)", indicating a possible duplicate or reinstallation.
Installation Path: Despite the installation, CMake throws an error saying it cannot find Visual Studio at the expected location:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (project):
Generator
Visual Studio 17 2022
could not find specified instance of Visual Studio:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools
However, the installer indicates that it's being installed into C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools, which is confusing because I was under the impression that 64-bit applications should reside in C:/Program Files.
Issue with CMake: Even though the Build Tools appear as installed in the Visual Studio installer, no corresponding "BuildTools" folder could be initially found on my system, which led me to use the separate installer.
Question: Should the Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools be installed in Program Files or Program Files (x86) on a 64-bit machine? How can I ensure that CMake correctly recognizes the installation path of the Build Tools to resolve the path issues?
Any insights or guidance on how to correctly configure the installation path for Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools and make it recognizable to CMake would be greatly appreciated!

I can only help with the first part. The name  "Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 (2)" just indicates that it has been downloaded twice. not that it has been installed twice. (I use the full Visual Studio, so don't know where the separate build tools are installed).

do you have a "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022" in your start menu?

I see that VS 2022 Build Tools does installed inC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools while the VS 2022 IDE installs in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Edition

I suspect that BuildTools only works if it is the ONLY edition installed on your system. If you have the IDE installed, then you need to add the build tools to that edition install instead of trying to install the other edition which is intended for cases where the IDE is NOT installed.
